# Add or update VersionIRI through OWL API

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api, iri

I have an ontology IRI without version. How to add or update version IRI of a particular OWL ontology ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a change object that sets the ontology id.
So, if you have an ontology `o` with an `IRI` but no version `IRI`:

```
OWLOntology o = ...
IRI versionIRI=IRI.create("version");
SetOntologyID change=new SetOntologyID(o, 
    new OWLOntologyID(o.getOntologyID().getIR(), Optional.of(versionIRI)));
o.getOWLOntologyManager().applyChange(change);
```